# Type error: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

I am trying to get late time. $latetime1 returning correct but $latetime2 not returning same as $latetime1. $systemIntime value format and $inTime value format are the same. But I am getting above error for $latetime2. What should be the correct one, please someone help me.
Here is my function bellow -

```
public function update(Request $request, Attendance $attendance)
{
    $attendance = Attendance::find($attendance->id);
    $inTime = $attendance->intime;
    // late time caculate
    $systemIntime = DB::table('schools')
                     ->join('users', 'schools.id', '=', 'users.school_id')
                     ->select('schools.intime')
                     ->first();
    $latetime1 = (new \DateTime($inTime))->format('H:i:s');
    $latetime2 = (new \DateTime($systemIntime))->format('H:i:s');
    $late      = $latetime1->diff($latetime2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the whole object instead of its property, so change this:

```
DateTime($systemIntime)
```

To:

```
DateTime($systemIntime->intime)
```

Comment: Now I am getting 'Call to a member function diff() on string' in $late;

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan that's because you're using `->format('H:i:s')` to convert DateTime object to a string. Just remove the `->format('H:i:s')` part from both objects.

Comment: Now What should I do to get the time difference, would you please tell me.

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan `diff()` should work for you if you remove `format()`